# Ошибка в системе проверки или действительно неудачный пример?

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок, аудит

В очереди на перезакрытие попался этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669296/asp-net-mvc-5-vs-core). Я вижу вопрос и понимаю, что чистая причина закрытия "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ".

[image]

Но оказывается "С этим вопросом нет никаких серьёзных проблем". Это я ошибаюсь или всё-таки этот вопрос зря не закрыли?

Comment: Я вам в вопрос меточку добавил. Там 12 вопросов всего (было, теперь 13). Почитайте.

Comment: @D-side Да без проблем.