# Несогласие с решением "Аудит провален"

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, аудит

Имеется [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/429053), который прекрасно помню, заданный месяц назад. Еще тогда его хотел отправить на закрытие по причине "Необходимо конкретизировать", но увидев необоснованную "заплюсованность" вопроса не стал этого делать.

Сейчас же, когда он попался в очереди проверок, и увидев, что на него нет принятых ответов, не задумываясь выбрал закрытие. В итоге: **Аудит провален**. Выйдя из очереди проверок, я всё же отправил на закрытие этот вопрос.

Приведу пример, схожего [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/980167/256824), где есть конкретика,  а не где автор "навтыкал" кучу `if`-ов и спрашивает "че делать?".

---

В-общем, я не согласен с этим решением проверки. Выходит, что я обязан пропускать или оставлять открытыми заплюсованные вопросы без принятых ответов спустя месяц?

Comment: А каков собственно вопрос?

Comment: @0xdb, в самом конце вопрос `Выходит, что я обязан...` и т.д.

Comment: Знак вопроса я там вижу. Всё равно несколько вопрос в целом непонятен. Касается он качества соощений выбранных системой для аудита или ваших действий во время/после аудита?

Comment: @0xdb, знак вопроса в самом конце. Так же вы можете ознакомиться со всем текстом вопроса и с описанием прикрепленных к нему меток. Ожидаю ответы в формате: *вопрос оставить открытым, потому что ...*,  *вопрос необходимо закрыть, потому что ...*. В качестве доводов важно услышать ваше мнение, опыт банов по проверкам, ссылки на инструкции и т.д., то есть никак не тот ответ, полученный от модератора Qwertiy.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, чем меньше вы будете заниматься закрыванием чего-либо, тем лучше будет для всех

Comment: @avp, ну то есть по вашему сайт должен представлять поток вопросов-ответов, а те механизмы, что были придуманы для систематизации - создаёт дискомфорт для его участников. Так вы считаете?

Comment: @РустамГимранов, в общем, да. Давно уже заметил, чем большее количество  людей вмешивается в процесс, тем менее интересным становится сайт. Вероятно это эффект самоцензуры

Comment: @avp, доверюсь вашему восьмилетнему пребыванию на сайте и перейму от вас `политику невмешательства` и `принцип самотека`.

Comment: @РустамГимранов _Так же вы можете ознакомиться со всем текстом вопроса и с описанием прикрепленных к нему меток_ - возможно не поверите, но ознакомился. Пост начинается так: _Имеется [вопрос],_ - но в ссылке не вопрос, там аудит. Или метки: [закрытие-вопросов] [аудит] - а как они между собой связаны? Существуют реальные сообщения и аудит сообщения. Последние генерируются системой на основе видоизменёных реальных сообщений. Больше никакой связи между этими двумя видами собщений нет. Более конкретное уточнение - когда вы пользуетесь термином _вопрос _, речь идёт об аудите или реальном вопросе?

Comment: @0xdb, не забивайте вы себе голову. Комментарием выше мною было принято решение по этому вопросу на мете и сложилось окончательное мнение о сайте в целом: никуда не лезть, ничего не предпринимать. Если [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1051989/256824) считается "ништяковсим", выходит, что я как-то не так интерпретировал раздел [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @РустамГимранов А, ну тогда следующее решение вашего вопроса. При малейшем подозрении, что это аудит - в заголовке вопроса ссылка на оригиннальный вопрос, откройте её в новой вкладке. Поступайте с оригинальным вопросом так, как считаете нужным - голосуйте/плюсуйте/минусуйте. Затем вернитесь во вкладку с аудитом. Здесь любые ваши действия никакого влияния на оригинальный вопрос не имеют. Поэтому, здесь руководствйтесь чем угодно: настроением, положением звёзд на небе итд, вы можете провалить/пройти аудит, ну или самое простое - закройте вкладку.

Comment: @0xdb, в том то и дело, что всегда открываю во второй вкладке вопрос, если на него есть ответ(ы). И не важно приняты они или нет, потому что нередки ситуации, когда вопрос недостаточно полно или корректно сформулирован, но ответы вытягивают этот вопрос. AntonShchyrov дал краткий адекватный ответ, но в комментариях к этому ответу возникла дискуссия по поводу исключений. И автор вопроса не участвовал в этих дискуссиях, а также не внес какие-либо уточняющие правки в сам вопрос.

Comment: @0xdb, именно поэтому я решил закрыть вопрос, но система сказала "Стоп!". На мете нашел схожий с моим вопросом, но он без ответов https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5447/256824 Вот я и спросил: выходит, что заплюсованные вопросы не нужно закрывать?

Comment: @РустамГимранов вопросы закрываются независимо от плюсов. Просто в данном случае вопрос в целом понятен. Почему его нужно закрывать с причиной "Необходимо конкретизировать"?

Answer (score -10, accepted):

Как оказалось данный сайт ruSO предназначен не для систематизации информации.

Сейчас -- это поток ежесекундных вопросов-ответов и рулетки для новичков.

Не тратьте своё время.

---

Спустя четыре месяца ни разу не попал из поискового запроса на этот сайт. Зато в обилии шлаковые ответы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1126043/256824

Comment: Мнение понятно, подобные опасения и раньше [высказывались](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/616/213987). Но ваш тезис "главное фармить карму" кажется верным только вам, это ваше личное мнение. Сообщество большое, неоднородное, у всех разные цели. Есть даже небольшое меньшинство, которое "сеет разумное, доброе, вечное" и мне бы подобные некорректные обобщения показались оскорбительными. Также хочу высказаться по поводу манифеста: его цель -- описать желаемое _идеальное_ устройство. Увы реальность всегда неидеальна, но это не повод утверждать, что идеал -- враньё. Это - ориентир, цель.

Comment: Ваши формулировки слишком резкие и переходят грань правил вежливого общения и помимо минусов на ответе проставлены неоднократные тревоги. Вынужден применить меры: либо удалить пост, либо убрать некоторые формулировки. Первая мера всегда крайне резко воспринимается авторами текстов, поэтому попробую ограничиться правкой. [Можете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7140/213987) удалить пост целиком, если считаете что ваш авторский посыл нарушен или попробовать привести пост в соответствие с правилами.

Comment: @AK: Вы не могли бы вкратце прояснить для публики, какую именно часть правил нарушает удалённый вами текст?

Comment: @VladD AK в целом уже ответил вроде. [CoC](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct). Не знаю, что ещё добавить. Это даже если отбросить тот факт, что ответ вообще на поставленный вопрос не отвечает.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Часть про ложь, что именно она нарушает? CoC большой, хочется конкретики, особенно тогда, когда речь идёт об удалении критического текста.

Answer (score 5):

Не вижу причин, по которым этот вопрос должен быть закрыт. В нём абсолютно всё понятно и сама тема полезная. Соответственно, в данном случае аудит провален верно.

Comment: Допустим это так. Вопрос отредактировал, чтобы он появился на главной. Посмотрим.

Comment: @Qwertiy как это отвечает на поставленный вопрос?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, это отвечает так: "в данном случае аудит провален верно".

Comment: Частично отвечает. Можешь в ответ добавить текст про то, что раз вопрос является онтопиком, то аудит провален верно?